# Intellij: Debugging does not work with Play Framework

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea, playframework, intellij-scala

I have problems for some time with debugging in Intellij (Ultimate 2019.2).

If I set Breakpoints and restart Intellij, or it reloads after a code change, all the Breakpoints work as expected:

[image: Before Start]

But if I set the Breakpoints when the Play server is running, only a few of them still work:

[image: After Start]

Is this a bug, or is my configuration wrong?

[image: debug config]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it worked with plain *sbt* (Thanks for the hint of @Gagandeep Kalra), I asked for support of Intellij:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-16565#comment=27-3792469

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart`

Intellij keeps reloading stuff, breakpoints become active only when it's truly sure, no false positives here.

Usually I do, start the server then debugger and make sure endpoints are active before I make the request.

Comment: what do you mean _I start the server then debugger_? Do you run first the play configuration and then attach a debugger?

Comment: yes, but that's all I have. The state you mention happens intermittently, usually resolves itself given some time, extreme cases I invalidate cache.

Comment: Did you try debugging from sbt?

Comment: Debugging with sbt works - so it seems to be a problem with Intellij.